# how to change text in notepad in c#?

Tags: c#

I have made a notepad in c#.The problem is when I made a notepad file with changing the font size and style,but when I open that file, the change does not seem on text. what I am doing wrong or missing to write in code of font tool? 
thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you saving the file?  Plain text doesn't have any font/style saved with it.

Comment: @DStanley: I am using following code-                                 private void fontToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FontDialog fd = new FontDialog();
            fd.Font = richTextBox1.SelectionFont;
            fd.Color = richTextBox1.SelectionColor;
            if (fd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                richTextBox1.SelectionFont = fd.Font;
                richTextBox1.SelectionColor = fd.Color;
            }
        }

Comment: That does not tell me how you are saving the file to disk.  Plain Text?  Rich Text?  HTML?

Comment: @user2683568 edit code into  your question.  don't post it in comments

Comment: @DStanley: ohh, sorry I didn't get you. I am saving by plain text. that means it doesn't have any effect  on text. now what should I do?

Comment: So you're not saving any of the font information with the text?  Just the plain text? Therein lies your answer.

Comment: Plain text does not have any style information associated with it. You will need to save the file as rich text. DStanley's answer below will help you with them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `RichTextBox` control has a [`SaveFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bf5hy2e.aspx) method:

```
richTextBox1.SaveFile(strFileName);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using winforms, you can get the rich text string by using the use the `Rtf` property

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    File.WriteAllText(@"c:\temp\richText.rtf", richTextBox1.Rtf);
}
```